# Providing custom OAuth2AccessTokenResponseClient to spring

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I have a demo spring boot app and I would like to configure oauth login as well my own custom token response client.

This is my configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {


    http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
            .and()
            .oauth2Login()
            .and()
            .oauth2Client()
                .authorizationCodeGrant()
                    .accessTokenResponseClient(customAccessTokenResponseClient());
}


private OAuth2AccessTokenResponseClient<OAuth2AuthorizationCodeGrantRequest> customAccessTokenResponseClient() {
    DefaultAuthorizationCodeTokenResponseClient client = new DefaultAuthorizationCodeTokenResponseClient();
    client.setRequestEntityConverter(new CustomOAuth2AuthorizationCodeGrantRequestEntityConverter());
    return client;
}

}
```

The login flow is working find, but it looks like my custom token response client is not getting registered. I put a break point in there, but the flow doesn't go through it. It looks like it is still using the defaults.

Am I missing something here or is the order wrong?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Figured out the issue.

The right way to configure is the following:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
                .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .oauth2Login()
                    .tokenEndpoint()
                        .accessTokenResponseClient(customAccessTokenResponseClient());
}
```